# Retrieve polygon paths using Google maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, vertices

When I draw a complex polygon with self-crosses using Google maps JS API v3 it is being split into simple polygons which are being filled with fill color. How can I retrieve the paths of the filled areas?

Example: for a polygon (0,0) - (2,0) - (2,-1) - (0,1) I need to get two paths describing two triangles: (0,0) - (1,0) - (0,1) and (1,0) - (2,0) - (2,-1)

[image]

Comment: Example in fiddle or at least a screenshot? I don't understand what you mean. A polygon is a polygon. You mean 2 overlapping polygons?

Comment: @MrUpsidown: it seems that user expects that crossing point should be vertex. It is not and that is correct. His example is like folded rectangle which produces two triangles. And it seems that user expects two paths. But path is only one.

Comment: @AntoJurković Right, I didn't get that but for sure it makes sense.

Comment: @AntoJurković what you have described is exactly what I mean. Google somehow knows how to fill the triangles. I need to retrieve paths of all filled areas.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've added an illustration and rewrote the question.

Comment: You will need to calculate the intersection point and add a vertex there (if you want one).  For four vertices as your example, that should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: @geocodezip it is a quite non-trivial task for a general case of n vertices. The map itself knows how to fill in the polygons, so I thought that it allows getting those filled areas.

Comment: Nope.  It doesn't allow that.  Agreed it is non-trivial for n vertices.